# Adding Numbers to a list using variable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm doing a programming question and I need a bit of help. 
I have a variable where I type in a number and then that number and all the numbers before it go in a list.

For example:
I pick 10 and put it in a variable

And all numbers from 1 - 10 are put in a list

Here is my code:

```
 Top_Num = int(input('Top Number'))
 Nums = []
```

Now lets say I chose 10 for the Top_Num, how do I put 10 numbers into the list?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can actually use Pythons built in `range(int)` function to do exactly this.

If you want the array to start at 1 and include the input number, you can use

```
Nums = list(range(1, Top_Num + 1))
```

The first argument of 1 indicates the start value of the array, and the second argument `Top_Num + 1` is the number that the array goes up to (exclusive).

Comment: On Python 3, you'll need to explicitly cast your `range` to a `list`: `list(range(1, Top_Num+1))`

Answer (score 2):

```
Nums = [num for num in range(1, Top_Num + 1)]
```

It uses list comprehensions too, which is (kinda) an important concept in python.